# MAAS node deployment failed with curtin installer

Tags: juju, maas

I have installed Ubuntu Server 15.10 with MAAS & have configured two nodes with the MAAS Server. The nodes reached to Ready State after commissioning. 
Then I run "juju bootstrap" on shell. One node went to Deploying state with the curtin installer. But after long time, the deployment failed with the following error on shell:

> ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-9ed9c196-81ee-11e5-bc54-001cc0f8442d/" is started but not deployed

Also, there was following error coming consistently in /var/log/maas/maas.log:

> maas.service_monitor: [ERROR] While monitoring service 'tgt' an error was encountered: Unable to parse the active state from systemd for service 'tgt', active state reported as 'failed'.

What could be the reason behind this? Please suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance!